# Ghostscript: Internal links annotations not-printing in PDF/A-1b

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdfa, pdf-annotations

i'm trying to generate a PDF/A-1b document with Ghostscript 9.18 from a batch of scanned document pages. I want to cover the scanned table of content with a layer of document internal links at the first page. But Ghostscript returns an error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.18: Annotation set to non-printing,
not permitted in PDF/A, annotation will not be present in output file
```

In commandline, i use:

```
gs \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-dBATCH=true \
-dNOPAUSE=true \
-sPAPERSIZE=a4 \
-dSAFER=true \
-sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor \
-sOutputFile=out.pdf \
-dEmbedAllFonts=true \
-dPrinted=true \
-dPDFA=true \
-dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 \
-sPDFSETTINGS=screen \
-f raw.pdf \
-f meta.ps
```

Each link is defined like:

```
[ /Rect [ 10 10 100 100 ] /ScrPg 1 /Page 7 /Subtype /Link /ANN pdfmark
```

I've tried to force the printing with the `/F 3` and `/F 4` PDF flag for annotations and on gs level with `-dPrinted=true` without any success.

Is there an other way to generate internal links in an PDF/A file? Do i misunderstand the PDF/A standard?

Comment: Its almost impossible to say for sure without seeing **precisely** what you are doing. If you think this should work, and doesn't, you have 2 choices; debug through the code yourself and see why the pdfwrite device thinks the annotation is invalid, or submit a bug report with a complete description of the problem and any required files, as well as a command line. Please do not attach any scripts, its entirely likely that the developer will be using a different OS and cannot use, or indeed understand, the script.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make your Link annotations non-printing. If you do not want them to have any visual appearance, just give them an appearance that does not draw anything (i.e. an empty appearance stream).

The PDF/A-1 standard mandates that all annotations that are visible (on screen) are also set to print (to ensure that the appearance of pages doesn't look different between display on a screen and printouts).

I unfortunately cannot help with how to use this information in or with GhostScript.